# Notes: Lines turn invisible when the line above them are deleted

Tags: catalina, notes.app

macOS Catalina.

Since one of the recent updates, formatting in Notes has gotten wonky. When you delete a line, the line under it can go invisible. Highlighting the invisible text and changing color manually fixes it, but this is not ideal behavior. Has anyone else ran into this, and does anyone have an idea on how to fix?

Comment: Is this on iOS or macOS?  I use Notes often on both platforms and haven't seen this behaviour.  What version?

Comment: MacOS, latest version (Catalina)

Comment: FYI, saying 'latest version' doesn't help if someone gets to this question after future releases of the OS and depending on when they read it.  See [ask] for tips on asking questions here.